# Convert Number to Word - Add "And" in between

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm currently using the vba below to convert numbers to word. All working fine except for example : 
520,000.00 it will convert to Five Hundred Twenty Thousand, but I want to achieve Five Hundred **and** Twenty Thousand instead. 
Where can I add that **"and"** in the formula below?

```
Function SpellNumber(ByVal MyNumber)
Dim Dollars, Cents, Temp
Dim DecimalPlace, Count
ReDim Place(9) As String
Place(2) = "Thousand "
Place(3) = "Million "
Place(4) = "Billion "
Place(5) = "Trillion "
' String representation of amount.
MyNumber = Trim(Str(MyNumber))
' Position of decimal place 0 if none.
DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")
' Convert cents and set MyNumber to dollar amount.
If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
    Cents = GetTens(Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & _
              "00", 2))
    MyNumber = Trim(Left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))
End If
Count = 1
Do While MyNumber <> ""
    Temp = GetHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3))
    If Temp <> "" Then Dollars = Temp & Place(Count) & Dollars
    If Len(MyNumber) > 3 Then
        MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)
    Else
        MyNumber = ""
    End If
    Count = Count + 1
Loop

Select Case Cents
    Case ""
        Cents = ""
    Case "One"
        Cents = " and One Cent"
          Case Else
        Cents = " and " & Cents & " Cents"
End Select
SpellNumber = Dollars & Cents
End Function

Function GetHundreds(ByVal MyNumber)
Dim Result As String
If Val(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function
MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)
' Convert the hundreds place.
If Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1) <> "0" Then
    Result = GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1)) & " Hundred "
End If
' Convert the tens and ones place.
If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
    Result = Result & GetTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2))
Else
    Result = Result & GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))
End If
GetHundreds = Result
End Function
```

Comment: There's something about writing cheque amounts on microsoft.com. It's been around for many years.

Comment: It's not for writting cheque purpose.

Comment: Whether it is or not is irrelevant; its the same method.

Comment: where does it concatenate the word "hundred"? Is it in the function GetHundreds?

Comment: @ John F yes from the function GetHundreds

Comment: @ChingLuTay then I think you need to post the code to GetHundreds function as i think that's where you need to change your code.

Comment: @ John F oh sorry, now i have included to the above.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is, if you have a hundreds digit greater than zero AND there is a non-zero digit in the tens OR the units, you need to add " and " after the work "hundred".

Ok in your GetHundreds after the code:

```
' Convert the hundreds place.
If Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1) <> "0" Then
    Result = GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1)) & " Hundred "
End If
```

insert the line

```
If CInt(MyNumber) > 100 Then Result = Result & "and "
```

See if that works for you.

EDIT: OOps too smart for my own good. Whole hundreds don't need " and " so try the following:

```
If CInt(MyNumber) Mod 100 <> 0 Then Result = Result & "and "
```

Comment: If the number is greater than 100 but has no tens or units, like 500 - would this evaluate to "Five Hundred and"?

Comment: Thanks @ John F. What does CInt stands for?

Comment: @ChingLuTay it's a function, see [this link](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/cint.php)

Comment: @John F It does work, but when it comes to digit like : 785650, it converted to Seven Hundred and Eighty Five Thousand Six Hundred and Fifty. It's so weird. It should be Seven Hundred Eighty Five Thousand Six Hundred and Fifty. Anywhere that I can amend the codes?

Comment: @ChingLuTay as far as I know, the way it comes out is correct i.e. you always say "...hundred AND...", no matter if it's hundreds, hundred thousand etc. What is the rule you need to follow with the use of "and"? In your original question it asked for Five Hundred and Twenty Thousand.

Comment: @John F I forgotten there's another scenario where I need that "and" at different position. Sorry!

Comment: @ChingLuTay no problem, I think there are different conventions around the world. Here is Oz we say hundred AND, but in the US the often leave the AND out altogether. Maybe try adding a boolean parameter to the GetHundreds called IsAndNeeded, and if it's false, don't execute that line of code I gave you.

Comment: @John F it won't work. I will try to think other solution. Thanks again for your help.