Adding "and" after hundreds in Spellnumber function
i needed a spellnumber function which adds a hyphen between the numbers like 45(Forty-Five), 23(Twenty-Three),etc and after some digging i got it but i also want this code to add an "and" after hundreds. For example for the number 34538.00 it should spell it as "Thirty-Four Thousand Five Hundred and Thirty-Eight". I hope i asked correctly what i need. i am attaching the code below.
Private sNumberText() As String


Public Function SpellNumber(NumberIn As Variant, Optional _
                AND_or_CHECK_or_DOLLAR_or_CHECKDOLLAR As String) As String
   Dim cnt As Long
   Dim DecimalPoint As Long
   Dim CardinalNumber As Long
   Dim CommaAdjuster As Long
   Dim TestValue As Long
   Dim CurrValue As Currency
   Dim CentsString As String
   Dim NumberSign As String
   Dim WholePart As String
   Dim BigWholePart As String
   Dim DecimalPart As String
   Dim tmp As String
   Dim sStyle As String
   Dim bUseAnd As Boolean
   Dim bUseCheck As Boolean
   Dim bUseDollars As Boolean
   Dim bUseCheckDollar As Boolean
  '----------------------------------------
  '  Begin setting conditions for formatting
  '----------------------------------------
   sStyle = LCase(AND_or_CHECK_or_DOLLAR_or_CHECKDOLLAR)
   bUseAnd = sStyle = "and"
   bUseDollars = sStyle = "dollar"
   bUseCheck = (sStyle = "check") Or (sStyle = "dollar")
   bUseCheckDollar = sStyle = "checkdollar"
  '----------------------------------------
  '  Check/create array. If this is the first
  '  time using this routine, create the text
  '  strings that will be used.
  '----------------------------------------
   If Not IsBounded(sNumberText) Then
      Call BuildArray(sNumberText)
   End If
  '----------------------------------------
  '  Begin validating the number, and breaking
  '  into constituent parts
  '----------------------------------------
   NumberIn = Trim$(NumberIn)
   If Not IsNumeric(NumberIn) Then
      SpellNumber = "Error - Number improperly formed"
      Exit Function
   Else
      DecimalPoint = InStr(NumberIn, ".")
      If DecimalPoint > 0 Then
         DecimalPart = Mid$(NumberIn, DecimalPoint + 1)
         WholePart = Left$(NumberIn, DecimalPoint - 1)
      Else
         DecimalPoint = Len(NumberIn) + 1
         WholePart = NumberIn
      End If
      If InStr(NumberIn, ",,") Or _
         InStr(NumberIn, ",.") Or _
         InStr(NumberIn, ".,") Or _
         InStr(DecimalPart, ",") Then
         SpellNumber = "Error - Improper use of commas"
         Exit Function
      ElseIf InStr(NumberIn, ",") Then
         CommaAdjuster = 0
         WholePart = ""
         For cnt = DecimalPoint - 1 To 1 Step -1
            If Not Mid$(NumberIn, cnt, 1) Like "[,]" Then
               WholePart = Mid$(NumberIn, cnt, 1) & WholePart
            Else
               CommaAdjuster = CommaAdjuster + 1
               If (DecimalPoint - cnt - CommaAdjuster) Mod 3 Then
                  SpellNumber = "Error - Improper use of commas"
                  Exit Function
               End If
            End If
         Next
      End If
   End If
   If Left$(WholePart, 1) Like "[+-]" Then
      NumberSign = IIf(Left$(WholePart, 1) = "-", "Minus ", "Plus ")
      WholePart = Mid$(WholePart, 2)
   End If
  '----------------------------------------
  '  Begin code to assure decimal portion of
  '  check value is not inadvertently rounded
  '----------------------------------------
   If bUseCheck = True Then
      CurrValue = CCur(Val("." & DecimalPart))
      DecimalPart = Mid$(Format$(CurrValue, "0.00"), 3, 2)
      If CurrValue >= 0.995 Then
         If WholePart = String$(Len(WholePart), "9") Then
            WholePart = "1" & String$(Len(WholePart), "0")
         Else
            For cnt = Len(WholePart) To 1 Step -1
              If Mid$(WholePart, cnt, 1) = "9" Then
                 Mid$(WholePart, cnt, 1) = "0"
              Else
                 Mid$(WholePart, cnt, 1) = _
                            CStr(Val(Mid$(WholePart, cnt, 1)) + 1)
                 Exit For
              End If
            Next
         End If
      End If
   End If
  '----------------------------------------
  '  Final prep step - this assures number
  '  within range of formatting code below
  '----------------------------------------
   If Len(WholePart) > 9 Then
      BigWholePart = Left$(WholePart, Len(WholePart) - 9)
      WholePart = Right$(WholePart, 9)
   End If
   If Len(BigWholePart) > 9 Then
      SpellNumber = "Error - Number too large"
      Exit Function
   ElseIf Not WholePart Like String$(Len(WholePart), "#") Or _
         (Not BigWholePart Like String$(Len(BigWholePart), "#") _
          And Len(BigWholePart) > 0) Then
      SpellNumber = "Error - Number improperly formed"
      Exit Function
   End If
  '----------------------------------------
  '  Begin creating the output string
  '----------------------------------------
  '  Very Large values
   TestValue = Val(BigWholePart)
   If TestValue > 999999 Then
      CardinalNumber = TestValue \ 1000000
      tmp = HundredsTensUnits(CardinalNumber) & "Quadrillion "
      TestValue = TestValue - (CardinalNumber * 1000000)
   End If
   If TestValue > 999 Then
     CardinalNumber = TestValue \ 1000
     tmp = tmp & HundredsTensUnits(CardinalNumber) & "Trillion "
     TestValue = TestValue - (CardinalNumber * 1000)
   End If
   If TestValue > 0 Then
      tmp = tmp & HundredsTensUnits(TestValue) & "Billion "
   End If
  '  Lesser values
   TestValue = Val(WholePart)
   If TestValue = 0 And BigWholePart = "" Then tmp = "Zero "
   If TestValue > 999999 Then
      CardinalNumber = TestValue \ 1000000
      tmp = tmp & HundredsTensUnits(CardinalNumber) & "Million "
      TestValue = TestValue - (CardinalNumber * 1000000)
   End If
   If TestValue > 999 Then
      CardinalNumber = TestValue \ 1000
      tmp = tmp & HundredsTensUnits(CardinalNumber) & "Thousand "
      TestValue = TestValue - (CardinalNumber * 1000)
   End If
   If TestValue > 0 Then
      If Val(WholePart) < 99 And BigWholePart = "" Then bUseAnd = False
      tmp = tmp & HundredsTensUnits(TestValue, bUseAnd)
   End If
  '  If in dollar mode, assure the text is the correct plurality
   If bUseDollars = True Then
      CentsString = HundredsTensUnits(DecimalPart)
      If tmp = "One " Then
         tmp = tmp & "Dollar"
      Else
         tmp = tmp & "Dollars"
      End If
      If Len(CentsString) > 0 Then
         tmp = tmp & " and " & CentsString
         If CentsString = "One " Then
            tmp = tmp & "Cent"
         Else
            tmp = tmp & "Cents"
         End If
      End If
   ElseIf bUseCheck = True Then
      tmp = tmp & "and " & Left$(DecimalPart & "00", 2)
      tmp = tmp & "/100"
   ElseIf bUseCheckDollar = True Then
      If tmp = "One " Then
         tmp = tmp & "Dollar"
      Else
         tmp = tmp & "Dollars"
      End If
      tmp = tmp & " and " & Left$(DecimalPart & "00", 2)
      tmp = tmp & "/100"
   Else
      If Len(DecimalPart) > 0 Then
        tmp = tmp & "Point"
        For cnt = 1 To Len(DecimalPart)
          tmp = tmp & " " & sNumberText(Mid$(DecimalPart, cnt, 1))
        Next
      End If
   End If
  '  Done!
   SpellNumber = Replace(NumberSign & tmp, "y-Thou", "y Thou")
   If Right(SpellNumber, 1) = "-" Then SpellNumber = Left(SpellNumber, Len(SpellNumber) - 1)
End Function


Private Sub BuildArray(sNumberText() As String)
   ReDim sNumberText(0 To 27) As String
   sNumberText(0) = "Zero"
   sNumberText(1) = "One"
   sNumberText(2) = "Two"
   sNumberText(3) = "Three"
   sNumberText(4) = "Four"
   sNumberText(5) = "Five"
   sNumberText(6) = "Six"
   sNumberText(7) = "Seven"
   sNumberText(8) = "Eight"
   sNumberText(9) = "Nine"
   sNumberText(10) = "Ten"
   sNumberText(11) = "Eleven"
   sNumberText(12) = "Twelve"
   sNumberText(13) = "Thirteen"
   sNumberText(14) = "Fourteen"
   sNumberText(15) = "Fifteen"
   sNumberText(16) = "Sixteen"
   sNumberText(17) = "Seventeen"
   sNumberText(18) = "Eighteen"
   sNumberText(19) = "Nineteen"
   sNumberText(20) = "Twenty"
   sNumberText(21) = "Thirty"
   sNumberText(22) = "Forty"
   sNumberText(23) = "Fifty"
   sNumberText(24) = "Sixty"
   sNumberText(25) = "Seventy"
   sNumberText(26) = "Eighty"
   sNumberText(27) = "Ninety"
End Sub


Private Function IsBounded(vntArray As Variant) As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next
   IsBounded = IsNumeric(UBound(vntArray))
End Function


Private Function HundredsTensUnits(ByVal TestValue As Integer, _
                              Optional bUseAnd As Boolean) As String
   Dim CardinalNumber As Integer
   If TestValue > 99 Then
      CardinalNumber = TestValue \ 100
      HundredsTensUnits = sNumberText(CardinalNumber) & " Hundred "
      TestValue = TestValue - (CardinalNumber * 100)
   End If
   If bUseAnd = True Then
      HundredsTensUnits = HundredsTensUnits & "and "
   End If
   If TestValue > 20 Then
      CardinalNumber = TestValue \ 10
      HundredsTensUnits = HundredsTensUnits & _
                          sNumberText(CardinalNumber + 18) & "-"
      TestValue = TestValue - (CardinalNumber * 10)
   End If
   If TestValue > 0 Then
      HundredsTensUnits = HundredsTensUnits & _
                          sNumberText(TestValue) & " "
   End If
End Function`


And what is not working with your posted code?

the code is working correctly, it does its job, however i want it to do one more job which is to add an "and" after hundreds

To add to what @Shrotter said, what's stopping you from doing it?  As it's written now, it's simply a work request, which doesn't make a good question on SO

Have you checked the optional parameter of the SpellNumber? It looks like adding an additional and in the string is already implemented.

i wanted to ask where can i write "and" in the above code to get the desired result. I came across a similar question over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51183565/convert-number-to-word-add-and-in-between

But since my sellnumber code is diffirent i am unable to use the solution provided in that question

@Shrotter I am not an expert in VBA but i checked the code and as you said, there is something already implemented about adding an additional "and" in the string, i am not sure. when i use the code, there is no "and" in the result. If it is already there in the code and there is a way to make it work then please let me know how.

Try to call the function like SpellNumber(34538.00, "and")

great.....it worked @Shrotter.....Thank you so much

Change in only two places needed
1. Removing hyphen between the numbers like 45(Forty-Five), 23(Twenty-Three)
in the line number of 250-251 of the module function HundredsTensUnits the changes
old code
    HundredsTensUnits = HundredsTensUnits & _
                          sNumberText(CardinalNumber + 18) & "-"

new code will be (just the hyphen sign will be replaced by blank space)
      HundredsTensUnits = HundredsTensUnits & _
                          sNumberText(CardinalNumber + 18) & " "

2. To add an "and" after hundreds
in the line number of 153-156 of the module function SpellNumber the changes
old code
If TestValue > 0 Then
      If Val(WholePart) < 99 And BigWholePart = "" Then bUseAnd = False
      tmp = tmp & HundredsTensUnits(TestValue, bUseAnd)
End If

new code will be with some additional line and new IF clause
 bUseAnd = True
 If TestValue > 0 Then
      If Val(WholePart) < 99 And BigWholePart = "" Then bUseAnd = False
      If (TestValue > 100 And Val(Right(Trim(Str(TestValue)), 2)) > 0) Then
        bUseAnd = True
      Else
        bUseAnd = False
      End If
      tmp = tmp & HundredsTensUnits(TestValue, bUseAnd)
End If

Implemented this on Microsoft Excel 2016.
